# Filter same value but against different column in SOQL

Tags: soql

I am having a output like this

```
_               Id                    AddressLine1__c                                   Application__c
Address__c  a080p00000N78DmAAJ  1627 Veterans Memorial Parkway East, Lafayette, IN, USA a0A0p0000015mX1EAI
Address__c  a080p00000N76nnAAB  1627 Veterans Memorial Parkway East, Lafayette, IN, USA 
Address__c  a080p00000N76nsAAB  1450 Navco Drive, Lafayette, IN, USA
```

I need to filter out 3 rd row and the condition has to applied on Application__c column.
I used the query like this

```
select  id,AddressLine1__c,Application__c  from Address__c where Application__c =''
```

and giving me output like this

```
                Id                      AddressLine1__c                                 Application__c
Address__c  a080p00000N76nnAAB  1627 Veterans Memorial Parkway East, Lafayette, IN, USA 
Address__c  a080p00000N76nsAAB  1450 Navco Drive, Lafayette, IN, USA
```

but i don't want the first row as `1627 Veterans Memorial Parkway East, Lafayette, IN, USA` is already having one ID mapped to it.

Actually My requirement is,  a user will search for address's to map to a particular application. First time when user searches I am showing the two address in drop down. When he selects one address then I will store that address mapped to that application Id. Second time in user drop down I have to show only one address as he already selects one address.If the user selects this address also then i will map the same application ID this address also.So third time I must not show any address in drop down as user already mapped the two address.

I can simply achieve this by updating the application ID against address but I must not do this as some other screen depends on this. This Empty Application ID has to be remain as it and must not be updated.

Comment: What does "is already having one ID mapped to it" mean? These records have different Ids. (Please [edit] your question to clarify).

Comment: Hi Davi Reed, I edited my question. Hope it will be clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query could have been a way to achieve this:

```
SELECT Id,AddressLine1__c,Application__c from Address__c WHERE Application__c = NULL AND AddressLine1__c NOT IN (SELECT Id,AddressLine1__c,Application__c from Address__c WHERE Application__c != NULL);
```

**Unfortunately, You cannot achieve this using a single SOQL as Salesforce doesn't support inner and outer selects on the same object.**

You will have to create a list using custom code. Below is the sample code.

```
Set<String> addressLineValues = new Set<String>();
for(Address__c addressObj:  [SELECT Id,AddressLine1__c,Application__c from Address__c WHERE Application__c !=NULL]) {
    addressLineValues.add(addressObj.AddressLine1__c);
}                        

List<Address__c> addressListToDisplay = [SELECT Id,AddressLine1__c from Address__c WHERE Application__c = NULL AND AddressLine1__c NOT IN :addressLineValues];
System.debug('addressListToDisplay::'+addressListToDisplay);
```